# Javascript Trapezoid area calculation with user input, incorrect result

Tags: javascript, area

I am trying to make a javascript program that calculates the area of a trapezoid. So far below is my js code:

```
var lol=prompt("Please enter which 2d polygon you would like this awesome calculator to calculate.")
if(lol==="trapezoid"){
    var tr1=prompt("Enter the top base.")
    var tr2=prompt("Enter the bottom base.")
    var tr3=prompt("Now enter the height.")
    confirm((tr1+tr2)*(tr3)/2)
}
```

But when I put 4,5,6 in my calculator, it spits out 135 instead of 27.

Why?

Comment: `confirm((+tr1 + +tr2)*(+tr3)/2)`

Comment: "4" + "5" = "45", not 9

Comment: Why the down votes? The OP has asked a reasonable question which they have made an attempt to solve.

Comment: @JackZelig look at the initial edit of this question.

Comment: Ah, ok. It seems to have been tidied up somewhat ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parseInt` to set the values as integers.

```
var lol=prompt("Please enter which 2d polygon you would like this awesome calculator to calculate.")
if(lol==="trapezoid"){
    var tr1=Number(prompt("Enter the top base."))
    var tr2=Number(prompt("Enter the bottom base."))
    var tr3=Number(prompt("Now enter the height."))
    confirm((tr1+tr2)*(tr3)/2)
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle with Benjamine's `Number` point

http://jsfiddle.net/cXWnk/

Comment: parseInt without the radix parameter is risky, might want to specify radix, although, you want to allow decimal numbers, so probably go for `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

The values you are getting back from the prompt are strings and, as Ryan P says, "1" + "1" = "11".

What you need to do is cast the strings to integers before using their values in the calculation.

You can do this with the `Number()` function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

So, your code might be:

```
confirm((Number(tr1) + Number(tr2)) *(Number(tr3))/2)
```

or, using the unary plus shorthand:

```
confirm((+tr1 + +tr2)*(+tr3)/2)
```